# Edge morphism of a particular spectral sequence

Tags: homological-algebra, derived-categories

I am not sure if this question is too elementary for MathOverflow and should strictly belong to Math StackExchange but I shall try my luck. Please feel free to close it in this case and I will migrate it over to the latter site.

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a left exact functor between categories
$\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ and assume the former has enough injectives. Suppose $A^{\bullet}$ is an object of $D^+(\mathcal{A})$. If I am not mistaken there exists an $E_1$ spectral sequence $E_1^{p,q} = R^q\mathcal{F}(A^p)\Rightarrow R^{p+q}\mathcal{F}(A^{\bullet}) = E^{p+q}$. I have a rough idea pertaining to the edge morphism $E_2^{p,0}\rightarrow E^{p}$ but could not wrap my head around the other edge morphism $E^{p}\rightarrow E_1^{0,p}$. Could someone provide an explicit description (or a hint or sketch how one can attain an explicit description) of this edge morphism? It does not seem very ''natural'' to me at first glance. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is just the morphism $R^p\mathscr{F}(A^{\bullet})\rightarrow R^p\mathscr{F}(A^0)$ deduced from the morphism $A^{\bullet}\rightarrow A^0$.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to deduce that by repeatedly taking kernels (of $d_{r}^{0,p}$) one ends up with an epimorphism $E^{p}\rightarrow E^{0,p}_{\infty}$ then?

Comment: I don't understand the question. This map is an epimorphism by definition of a spectral sequence. Do you want to deduce that from a more or less explicit diagram chasing?